# ambari server 2.7.3 installing host on step 3 error

Tags: ambari

I have build ambari 2.7.3 from source, so I cleanly install ambari and then install 2.7.3 following the instructions from: [https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Installation+Guide+for+Ambari+2.7.3](http://ambari%202.7.3)

Fresh install ambari server 2.7.3  installing host on step 3 ambari server get this error code :

```
/var/lib/ambari-agent/bin/ambari-agent: line 23: buildNumber: unbound variable
```

Answer (score 0):

edit file *ambari-agent* with notepad

> /root/var/lib/ambari-agent/bin/*ambari-agent*

edit HASH and fill with version that has been converted to md5

```
set -u # fail on unset variables
VERSION="2.7.3.0"
HASH=" -md5 code here- "
```

example:

```
set -u # fail on unset variables
VERSION="2.7.3.0"
HASH="fa14de4a50197357f7c5c0e1b3486df2"
```

save and *restart ambari-agent*